# How is suitable to input the subnet value for an AWS EC2 in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I would like ask what is the suitable way to input the subnet value for an AWS EC2 instance in Terraform? For a stand-alone EC2 instance, not created by ASG.

 I am using the below EC2 instance Terraform module (just a snippet shown here):

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2-instance" {
  count = var.EC2_instance_count
  subnet_id = length(var.network_interface) > 0 ? null : element(distinct(compact(concat([var.subnet_id],var.EC2_private_subnet_ids))),count.index,)
...
}
```

In the `variables.tf` file the `subnet_id` and `EC2_private_subnet_ids` are:

```
variable "subnet_id" {
  description = "The VPC Subnet ID to launch in"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "EC2_private_subnet_ids" {
  description = "A list of subnets required for this instance from the VPC the EC2 will be deployed into"
  type        = list(any)
  default     = []
}
```

When I call the module this is the value for `EC2_private_subnet_ids` :

```
EC2_private_subnet_ids      = vpc.outputs.private_app_subnet_ids
```

The `vpc.outputs.private_app_subnet_ids` value is:

```
private_app_subnet_ids = [
  "subnet-0g21718c32449dc5c",
  "subnet-0d7c222ec57b67bb4",
]
```

For `EC2_instance_count = 1` and `subnet_id` as default value (""), the subnet_id of the EC2 instance will be `subnet-0g21718c32449dc5c` (the element with index 0).


My questions would be:

1. If one or more private subnets are added, then can the elements in the list `subnet_id` change order? If yes, then it may be that `subnet-0g21718c32449dc5c` is not anymore the element with index 0 and at a subsequent `terraform apply` the EC2 instance to be recreated (argument forces replacement; e.g. for ec2 are  key-pair, subnet). In this case, would it be "best-practice" to input the subnet value directly as `subnet_id = "subnet-0g21718c32449dc5c"` in the module inputs?
2. In this Terraform EC2 module example:
   https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-ec2-instance/blob/main/examples/complete/main.tf the 
   `subnet = module.subnets.private_subnet_ids[0]` is also given using the index. Same question, what if the list private_subnet_ids changes (subnets are added/deleted), is it "safe" to give the subnet value based on index of a list.
3. In the EC2 module snippet above, after `count.index` in the function `element` there is a `,` . Is it a mistake? Somehow there is no error and the EC2 is created successfully. I mean the syntax is `element(list, index)` .


   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. I've never seen those change order later, but I also don't see anything in the documentation guaranteeing the order will never change. So if you want to be sure the order will never change you should call [sort](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/sort) on the list before referencing a specific index like `[0]`.

   It is definitely not best practice to hard-code the subnet ID like you are suggesting. Best practice would be to reference the output of the resource, or if you aren't creating the subnet then use a data source to look it up and not have it hard-coded at all. If you hard-code the subnet ID then you won't be able to re-use this Terraform code later if you needed to rebuild your infrastructure or deploy to a different AWS region. Again, if you are worried about the list order changing, rely on `sort()` to guarantee the order.
2. Same answer as #1
3. That extra `,` does look like a mistake. I think Terraform is just ignoring it.